# Does Node JS API data flow

Tags: reactjs, node.js, google-cloud-dataflow, web-architecture

We have a React web app hosted in Microsoft Azure. That connects to an API layer which then connects to our backend services and databases.
When a user loads a page, does the react web app connect to/store/route the data? Or does the data go directly from the client's computer to the API layer?

i.e. If I have a web app hosted in Singapore and the API layer & backend services hosted in Australia. When a user in Australia loads the web page, does the data that is requested leave Australia? Or does the client computer connect directly to the API layer?

The web app is ReactJS & NodeJS and uses Axios to make the API calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but here are the basics.
When users access your React web app, the content they interact with typically originates from your backend services via an API. So, when someone in Australia loads your web page, the initial loading of the web page itself (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) happens from the Singapore server. Subsequently, any data requests made by the web page are directed to the API, which is hosted in Australia. Since the API resides in Australia, the data requests do not need to leave the country to reach the API for processing, again as I said your question is very unclear but where ever the API is hosted the client will need to connect to that server to fetch any data.